# Data persistence in iframe

Tags: angular, iframe

I have two pages say A and B. Page A consists of an iframe and the iframe contains a form which the user edits. I want that when my user navigates to some other page and then comes back to page A.. the changes that he made should persist. Is it possible?

Note: I cannot make any changes to the iframe code as it is provided by a third party.